# reactivate WD Smartware VCD for My Book for Mac

Tags: mac, undo, vcd

I have used:

```
sudo sh -c "echo UUID=`diskutil info /Volumes/WD\ SmartWare/ | grep 'UUID' | awk '{print $NF}'` none hfs rw,noauto 0 0 >> /etc/fstab"
```

to deactivate the VCD but now want to lock the drive again using the VCD so i'd like to reverse the above code. But i'm a bit unsure what code i need to use as etc/fstab didn't exist originally.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, `sudo cat /etc/fstab` and verify it contains only a single line. Then `sudo rm /etc/fstab` will delete the file. Since it didn't exist before, all settings will be reverted to default.

---

If there's more than one line, there should be only a single line containing `none hfs rw,noauto 0 0` toward the end. Enter `sudo vim /etc/fstab`, move the cursor to that line using arrow keys, press `dd` (will not be printed), then enter `:wq`and press `Enter`. Follow this description to the letter.